# Difference between Color and SolidColorBrush clarification

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, graphics, colors

Ok this has been bugging me and I haven't really found any kind of definitive answer as the the reason/cause of the difference between `Color` & `SolidColorBrush` so I'm wondering if someone can educate me on this.

I already know the differences in usage, like for example I can use a `SolidColorBrush` in a dependency like if I say;

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlahBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<Border Background="{StaticResource BlahBrush}"/>
```

but then say I throw the same resource in an `EasingColorKeyFrame` kind of like;

```
<EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BlahBrush}" />
```

then it's going to puke at me about it being a SolidColorBrush....except then I can get around that by just declaring it via a resource chain back to a `Color` kind of like;

```
<Color x:Key="OriginalBlahBrush">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlahBrush" Color="{StaticResource OriginalBlahBrush}"/>
```

and it will be just fine....but then again I could just utilize the `Color` property alone of the `SolidColorBrush` and can get the same behavior without being separated kind of like;

```
<SolidColorBrush>
     <SolidColorBrush.Color>
        <Color A="255" R="0" G="0" B="255" />
     </SolidColorBrush.Color>
</SolidColorBrush>
```

So I guess my question is, what is the inherent difference between the Colors and SolidColorBrush class's and the reason for their weird quirks in usage? aka I guess what's the reason for   System.Windows.Media.Colors vs System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush if they're both just giving a solid damn color??

Inquiring minds want to know! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Remarks section in [Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.aspx):

> A Brush "paints" or "fills" an area with its output. Different brushes
>   have different types of output. Some brushes paint an area with a
>   solid color, others with a gradient, pattern, image, or drawing. The
>   following list describes the different types of WPF brushes:
>
> **•SolidColorBrush: Paints an area with a solid Color.**
>
> •LinearGradientBrush: Paints an area with a linear gradient.
>
> •RadialGradientBrush: Paints an area with a radial gradient.
>
> •ImageBrush: Paints an area with an image (represented by an
>   ImageSource object).
>
> •DrawingBrush: Paints an area with a Drawing. The drawing may include
>   vector and bitmap objects.
>
> •VisualBrush: Paints an area with a Visual object. A VisualBrush
>   enables you to duplicate content from one portion of your application
>   into another area; it's very useful for creating reflection effects
>   and magnifying portions of the screen.

Comment: But wherein it's referencing a single solid color, why would something like a frame care? I could see if the Brush is specifying one of the others it might, but I would assume it to accept a solidcolor be it Brush or Color? :/

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. In WPF you fill (or draw strokes) with Brushes only, not with Colors. So in order to fill an area with a single color, you need a special Brush that does exactly that, i.e a SolidColorBrush.

Comment: Actually I think you did help explain just with that, basically Color wants a single value, while I guess Brush wants whatever it's going to repeat to fill "brush" an area. I'll accept that, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is the following.

- Color represents a specific color { red, blue, … } etc.
- SolidColorBrush represents specific Color and the ability to use the color to paint an area.
- Color is a struct data type that holds the details of color.
- SolidColorBrush is a class that holds Color objects and adds Opacity and transformation properties.
- Colors list pre-set number of colors. 
  Color c = Colors.Red;
- Brushes Lists pre-set number of Brushes.
  SolidColorBrush br = Brushes.Red;

Answer (score 1):

`Color` is a component of `SolidColorBrush` and one of it constructor has Color-type parametr. If you want to fill some components on the forms first you need to create color and after create `SolidColorBrush` based on that color which you was created earlier. It's like a real clear brush and color palette, where you need to soak the brush for painting/filling something.
`Color` object is more "low-level" and you can set some color with A, R, G, B-parameters. 
And `SolidColorBrushes` is a type of brushes for filling object (inheritance from System.Windows.Media.Brush). You can combine colors in one Brush.