# Clipping behaviour on custom BorderBrush

Tags: wpf, xaml, border

I have a simple rounded border with a solid brush:

```
 <Border BorderThickness="2,0,2,0" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" BorderBrush="Green"/>
```

[image]

Looks as I expect. Now, I want the border to have a dashed stroke:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2,0,2,0" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10">
      <Border.BorderBrush>
         <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
               <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Green" StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                   Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                   Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                   StrokeDashCap="Square"/>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
          </VisualBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>    
  </Border>
```

[image]

That somehow clips the border in a weird way I can't understand. I thought it would be the way the brush is painted, but I can't make out any pattern. There should be no clipping with the inner content of the border (the red thing you can partly see) as it looks doesn't clip in that way in any other case.

If I set the StrokeThickness a bit higher, I looks more acceptable:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2,0,2,0" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10">
          <Border.BorderBrush>
             <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                   <Rectangle StrokeThickness="4" Stroke="Green" StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                       Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                       Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                       StrokeDashCap="Square"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
              </VisualBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>    
      </Border>
```

[image]

Can someone explain why that looks so strange? The appearance also changes if I set a different width or height for the rectangle - also in a way I don't understand. The position of the strokes and gaps changes, but not in a way I can make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're doing it via a brush. What you see would actually be expected.

@Clemens actually helped me with an explanation to [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467296/difference-between-color-and-solidcolorbrush-clarification) I had some time ago by being kind enough to show some Doc snippets.

> A Brush "paints" or "fills" an area with its output. Different brushes have different types of output. Some brushes paint an area with a solid color, others with a gradient, pattern, image, or drawing.
>
> •VisualBrush: Paints an area with a Visual object. A VisualBrush enables you to duplicate content from one portion of your application into another area; it's very useful for creating reflection effects and magnifying portions of the screen.

So the are being "painted" is determined by the area it's allowed, in this case from the parent panel providing the area within it's `BorderBrush` so we see a predictable pattern provided by the parent.

[image]

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: That explains the second picture, but why is the brush from the third picture able to cross this area?

Comment: @Lennart Because it's basically the equivalent of taking one panel, embedding another in it and giving the inner one a margin. The lower z-index panel would be the area "painted" by the brush. If I have some free time later I'll make some more pretty pictures to explain better. :)